# How change the border (inside part) color of a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border, jsplitpane

I'm writing an application that will run in fulscreen. Sor far there is a thin border around the whole screen.

This thin border creates a thin gray line around the screen.
I want to remove this line (see red arrow on the picture).

[image]

Here is how I build the full screen window:

```
final JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Display Mode");
mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
mainFrame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
mainFrame.setResizable(false);
mainFrame.setUndecorated(true);

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 0, fill"));

GraphicsDevice defaultScreenDevice  = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
JSplitPane spMain = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftWhiteJPanel, rightBlackJPanel);

spMain.setDividerLocation(defaultScreenDevice.getDisplayMode().getWidth() / 2);

panel.add(spMain, "grow");
mainFrame.add(panel);

mainFrame.pack();
defaultScreenDevice.setFullScreenWindow(mainFrame);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The border is coming from the `JSplitPane`, trying removing the border with `setBorder(null)` for example...

```
spMain.setBorder(null);
```

Comment: MadProgrammer you're a genius !! The border is out now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative - Add a line border to your panel.
Example: `yourPanelName.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));`

Comment: XD I swear I didnt see that the first time I looked at it!

Comment: I didn't see a thing ;)